# replace part of attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, regex, json, replace

I have a page with the following div

```
<div class="info" attribute-one="value one" attribute-two="value two" json="see below"></div>
```

The "json" attribute is filled with a compressed JSON string similar to

```
{
  "serviceContext": "\/",
  "state": "READY",
  "url": "http://domain.com/some-url.extension",
  "zoomedPageWidth": 768,
  "hits": [

  ],
  "httpContentLoaded": 0,
  "resource": "\/session\/zc7d2c08-90d8-4b2d-97f8-a455b28c4e7d\/",
  "httpContentLength": 660032
}
```

Now I want to replace the resource parameter in the JSON string, from:

```
"resource": "\/session\/bc7d2c28-90d9-4b2d-97f8-a455b28c4e7d\/",
```

to

```
"resource": "http:\/\/domain.com\/page\/session\/bc7d2c28-90d9-4b2d-97f8-a455b28c4e7d\/",
```

But I have no idea how to do this with regular expressions in JavaScript. Anyone kind enough to help me out with this?

Answer (score 4):

What i would do is skip the regex, and parse as JSON:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(theJsonString);
jsonObject.resource = "http://domain.com/page" + jsonObject.resource;
theJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

It's up to you to put `theJsonString` into the element.

Comment: I would post the same answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can yse some JQuery and JOSN functions

[Take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyaursyh/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="test" json='{"serviceContext": "\/", "state": "READY","url": "http://domain.com/some-url.extension","zoomedPageWidth": 768,"hits": [],"httpContentLoaded": 0,"resource":"\/session\/zc7d2c08-90d8-4b2d-97f8-a455b28c4e7d\/","httpContentLength": 660032}'></div>
```

and JS:

```
var testElement = $('#test'),
    a = testElement.attr('json');
    o = JSON.parse(a);

o.resource = 'http://domain.com/page/session' + o.resource;
testElement.attr('json', JSON.stringify(o));
```